# Not able to access fields of structs

Tags: go

I am trying to implement linked list of struct in Go using list package available. This is the sample code below -

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct{
    B int 
}

func main() {
    l := list.New()
    for i:=0;i<5;i++ {
        c := A{i}
        l.PushFront(c)
    }

    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }

}
```

Output I get is in form `{0}` and same for other iterations. How can I access the field to get the integer value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the list item back to `A`. You can see it running [here](https://play.golang.org/p/QENzCBButP).

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    B int
}

func main() {
    l := list.New()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        c := A{i}
        l.PushFront(c)
    }

    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        v := e.Value.(A)
        fmt.Println(v.B)
    }

}
```

Comment: It was great help for beginner like me.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting access to the structure through e.Value, but you are not getting access to the structures value. You will need to do e.Value.B

Comment: I tried that but it just gives an error as the value undefined .